# Leave my secondDialog and continue with RootDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a RootDialog, who contains 3 paths BTCDialog, LTCDialog and ETHDialog.
When I go through the first dialog like BTCDialog i execute my code, and I need to get out when my dialog is finish (for example because I need to launch LTCDialog)
I go through BTCDialog with

```
await context.Forward(new BTCDialog(), this.ResumeAfterDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

When I finish I get out to BTCDialog with
context.Done(argument);
So I executed my function in RootDialog

```
private async Task ResumeAfterDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
```

My problem is when my method ResumeAfterDialog is executed I have an information (result) who contains a message I could use in my RootDialog
How write my method ResumeAfterDialog to continue the dialog with my user ? I would like execute directly the method MessageReceivedAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your result is of type `IMessageActivity`, then you can just call the `MessageReceivedAsync` method instead of waiting for the next message.

```
private async Task ResumeAfterDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;

    await MessageReceivedAsync(context, Awaitable.FromItem(activity));
}
```

As a side note, if your `BTCDialog` dialog will be always returning an `IMessageActivity`, you should update your dialog to be IDialog and in that way you can update your `ResumeAfterDialog` method to receive an `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>` instead of `IAwaitable<object>` saving you for doing the cast.